# Group rings and projective modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, homological-algebra

If $A$ is a lattice (i.e. a fin. gen. free $\mathbb{Z}$-module), and $G$ is some group which acts on $A$, will $A$ be a projective $\mathbb{Z}[G]$-module?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly not, as the action can be trivial!

Comment: And it is very rare that $\mathbb Z$ be a projective $\mathbb Z[G]$-module.

Comment: Ah yes I didnt think about the action being trivial, thank you.

Comment: Notice that there are many other actions which will give non-projective modules, also.